# Run function after second load

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This script alerts when the content of iframe has changed. But unfortunetly, it alerts when the first page load also. So how can I get this work only after first page load ?

```
$(function(){
$('#iframe').load(function() {
    alert("the iframe has changed.");
});
});
```

Comment: please, explain in more detail please. Does it require to store the count for page loads here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a counter variable to keep track of how many times it's been previously loaded and then act accordingly based on the count.

```
$(function(){
var loadCnt = 0;
$('#iframe').load(function() {
    if (loadCnt > 0) {
         alert("the iframe has changed.");
    }
    ++loadCnt;
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try to save the loaded state in the data object.

like this:

```
$(function(){
    jQuery('#iframe').load(function() {
        var iframe = $(this);
        if(iframe.data('loaded')) {
            alert("the iframe has changed.");
        }
        iframe.data('loaded', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a `bool` to track whether or not this is the first load.

```
$(function(){
  var isFirstLoad = true;
  $('#iframe').load(function() {
    if (!isFirstLoad) {
      alert("the iframe has changed.");
    }
    isFirstLoad = false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way - store a count, don't action on the first iteration.

```
$(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $('#iframe').load(function() {
        if (i++) alert("the iframe has changed.");
    });
});
```